# Rails scope with HABTM relationship count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have an Event class with a HABTM relationship with a User class. I'm trying to create a Event scope that includes only Events that have 2 Users associated with it.

I currently have a Event#status method that returns the following:

```
def status
  self.users.length == 2 ? "matched" : "not matched" 
end
```

So now basically I'm trying to find how to write a scope that includes all "matched" events. I tried `scope :matched, self.users.length == 2`, which didn't work at all, but is there a similar way that I'm missing?

EDIT: This class method does this correctly, but it'd still be nice if I could encapsulate it in a scope.

```
def self.pending
  Event.all.map { |e| e if e.status == "matched" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems here. Right now, your `status` method is returning literal strings, which is a bit surprising -- it would be more common to have this return a Boolean value. Also, the name `status` is not descriptive -- perhaps `exactly_two_users?` would be better. In addition, if you use `users.count` instead of `users.length`, then the DB will do the count more efficiently.

Your scope could simply be `where(:users.count => 2)`, I believe.

Comment: I actually simplified the method a little bit, it's supposed to return three different statuses. `where(:users.count => 2)` didn't work, unfortunately - it says there's no count method for a symbol.

Comment: Maybe `'users.count'` would work instead; I just did a quick search for the syntax with no success. Anyway, that's the basic idea.